# WP administration over SSL using different domain

Tags: admin, ssl, domain

I had originally installed Wordpress at https://elektrik.fweise.de, and later changed the url to http://elektrik.cafe (which I'd like the site's domain to be). However, I only have a SSL certificate for https://fweise.de and its subdomains.

I wish to keep http://elektrik.cafe as the main public domain, but to be able to log in and access the admin area through https://elektrik.fweise.de/wp-admin

Is it possible?

Comment: Depending on your server configuration it may not be possible. Have you tried to change the url in settings? ( WordPress Address (URL) in General > Settings. )

Comment: You can use LetsEncrypt to acquire free SSL certificates for the other domains, you don't have to pay for certificates unless you want the extended validation types that put your company name in the address bar

Comment: sadly my web hosting provider (1&1 Germany) doesn't support LetsEncrypt, and neither have I administrative rights to install it through the shell :(